# How to find the XPath to click the image having same name

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the image `<img>` w.r.t to the "TM100" mentioned in the `td` tag. Please can anyone give me the XPath.

I'm facing issue in the selecting the image. Because all the image are having the same xpath.

```
<tr>
<td>
<div id='xxx' class='avatar_standalone' ...>
<div class ='yyy'>
<div class ='zzz'>
<a oncontextmenu="return false" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="xxx('MINE|XX0172', '2');>
<img class="newassetIcon assetIcon linkable" src="https://xxxx/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015d00000020ZaWAAU&oid=00Dd0000000eu33&lastMod=1377179945000"/>
</a>
<span class="imgData" style="display: none;">MINE|XX0172</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);">XX0172</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211); text-align: center;">6073.7</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);">TM2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div id='xxx' class='avatar_standalone' ...>
<div class ='yyy'>
<div class ='zzz'>
<a oncontextmenu="return false" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="xxx('MINE|XX0172', '2');>
<img class="newassetIcon assetIcon linkable" src="https://xxxx/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015d00000020ZaWAAU&oid=00Dd0000000eu33&lastMod=1377179945000"/>
</a>
<span class="imgData" style="display: none;">MINE|XX0172</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);">XX0172</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211); text-align: center;">1073.7</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);">TM3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div id='xxx' class='avatar_standalone' ...>
<div class ='yyy'>
<div class ='zzz'>
<a oncontextmenu="return false" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="xxx('MINE|XX0172', '2');>
<img class="newassetIcon assetIcon linkable" src="https://xxxx/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015d00000020ZaWAAU&oid=00Dd0000000eu33&lastMod=1377179945000"/>
</a>
<span class="imgData" style="display: none;">MINE|XX0172</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);">XX0172</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211); text-align: center;">8073.7</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);">TM100</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this one, might be this could works for you:

```
//tr[descendant::td[contains(text(),'TM100')]]//img[@class='newassetIcon assetIcon linkable']
```

> I have tested the above code using this:

```
//tr[descendant::td[contains(text(),'TM100')]]//td[contains(text(),'XX0172')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `img` element you can use the following XPath

```
//tr[td = 'TM100']/div[@id = 'xxx']/div[@class = 'yyy']/div[@class = 'zzz']/a/img
```

If you want to click the image you might want to select the `a`, so the following works:

```
//tr[td = 'TM100']/div[@id = 'xxx']/div[@class = 'yyy']/div[@class = 'zzz']/a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm getting the Error  as : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

Comment: how to verify the xpath is correct or not in chrome browser ?? Is there any tool available ???

Comment: @Thyagu: [Evaluate and validate XPath/CSS selectors in Chrome Developer Tools](http://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: @Thyagu Also, if you are using Selenium and are inexperienced in XPath you might want to consider the Selenium IDE (see http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)